# How to add mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb property to EMR Cluster in Cloud Formation template?

Tags: emr, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce, aws-cloudformation

I've been taking a look on how to modify the default values that EMR gives to the cluster depending on the type of machine it is.

In my case, it's a pretty basic setup of a `m4.large` as master and `c3.2xlarge` as core and the same for the task. The value that EMR sets for this property in the Task is `2880` (from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html). However, I need to increase this default value.

I've been trying to change this default configuration in my Cloud Formation template but for some reason it doesn't accept it. This is what I'm adding to the CF template, I can't seem to find any examples of this online:

```
    "Configurations" : [{
      "Classification": "mapred-site",
      "Properties": {
        "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb": "4096"
    }}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If an answer below solved your question, don't forget to [mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/327137). If your question is still not answered, please provide additional details so others can help better answer your question.

Comment: @wjordan thanks, you just earned me extra some points. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, the solution for me was the change the key name from `Properties` to `ConfigurationProperties` because the syntax in CF specifically seems to be a bit different than you'd use within EMR's config section.

Try this:

```
"Configurations": [
  {
      "Classification": "mapred-site",
      "ConfigurationProperties": {
        "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb": "4096"
      },
      "Configurations": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked, but I found out that for my specific case, I needed the default value to stay low, but only be set to 4096 on some jobs. I discovered how to set this in the application specific scenario I'm using (Druid batch ingestion).